# what will happen if i delete my bind mount file while the container is running?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grafana, docker-volume

what will happen if i delete my bind mount file while the container is running ?

i am using a grafana image that is running on a container and i specified a bind mount

```
volumes:
- ./data/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
```

but when i delete the directory /data/grafana/ while my container is running i can still find my  dashboard and my data unless i restart the container which is normal to not find any thing

my question is that  any change on the host file is updated immediately on the container file ?

Answer (score 3):

The way most Linux/Unix filesystems work, when you delete a file or directory all you are actually doing is deleting entry in the lookup table that maps a filename to what is known as an inode.

When an application opens a file it uses the lookup table to find the inode and from then on all actions take part on the inode. So if an application has a file open and you delete it, the application will continue to work normally and be able to read/write to the file. Once the application is closed there will be no way to access that inode again so any changes to the (now deleted) file will be lost.

The same applies to the bind mount. When you delete the directory, the container still has a valid handle to the inode that represents the base directory and will continue to work normally until the container is destroyed.